# Do the self-induction cause change in magnetic field which again causes a self induction?

Tags: self-induction

my question is: It is known that for a coil, if current is changed then the magnetic field inside the coil is changed, and the coil tries to oppose this change by inducting itself   However, should not we be concerning with the rest? I mean, the self inductance means that current was not changed as it was supposed to change, rather it increased or decreased more "smoothly". The change in current due to self-inductance must -according to me- cause again a change in magnetic field which again causes -a less effective- self induction and it goes like this.  Does something like this indeed exist and do we just ignore that in questions(freshman engineering) or is it something I made up?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your phrasing is rather confusing. If you're asking what I think you're asking, this is the physical origin of self-inductance. It's not ignored in freshman engineering because it's the origin of all the equations you might have been taught. But I honestly am not sure what you're asking, so....

Comment: @Felthry Change in current => change in magnetic field

Comment: @Felthry Change in current produces change in magnetic field. And the coil opposes this change(Lenz Law) by producing an emf on itself. I am asking whether this produced emf also produces a change in magnetic field?

Comment: Okay, I understand your question now. I'm not confident in my ability to properly explain the answer, though, so I'll leave it to someone else.

Comment: Welcome to Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange.  Be sure to take the tour to get the most out of this site:  https://electronics.stackexchange.com/Tour

Comment: Delightfully, the solitary inductor is a feedback system, with magnetic flux being the feedback path.

Answer (score 0):

At first: The descriptions A cause B and B cause C does not mean any time difference. A, B and C occurs at the same time when we talk about electric and magnetic fields. That clear? I hope so and continue.

If you look at Maxwell equations about what is caused by the changes of the field strengths, it really is as you commented to user Felthry: Non-zero inductive emf really causes a magnetic field except in one special case. That case is: The current grows or decreases at constant speed (A/s), has allways done so and will continue it forever. In other cases there exists a radio wave.

In practical coils we very likely use so slowly changing currents that the second order effect "the magnetic field that is caused by the induced emf" can be ignored without a big error. Actually we ignore the radio wave that occurs around the inductor and spreads to the space.

When it can be ignored? As long as the dimensions of the coil are so small that all changes occur practically at the same time in the whole coil. Increase the frequency or make the coil bigger, the error grows. There's no strict limit, when coils become useless. One adage or maxim about it is "keep the maximum dimensions of your circuit equal or less than 2% of the wavelength, then you can ignore the in-circuit waves and get usable results by calculating currents and voltages.